# Populate UITableView with youtube thumbnail

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube, youtube-api

I have an app that has a video section, the idea is to have a tableview that will display a youtube thumbnail and infos about the video on each row. I know how to get the videos on a regular view with UIWebView but how can i have that on a cell?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [gdata-objective-c client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/). It [supports the YouTube data API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Source/Clients/YouTube) so you can get thumbnail and other info about a video using this library.

Comment: How do i integrate that to my tableview?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) for that.

Comment: Do you know a link to a tutorial to implement this?

Comment: Actually i know how to get the tableview thing going it's the api that i wasn't familiar with but i will look into that thanks

Comment: Cool. If you need to, I think the Table View Programming Guide is the probably the best tutorial you can read on table views. Its a bit long but its worth going through.